# Appending a Counter() list to a pygtk treestore (Python)

Tags: python, arrays, list, pygtk

I'm currently attempting to append a sorted list of items to a pygtk treestore.
The list is a count of the times the number occurs in the original list, eg. 2 lots of 24

**Generating the list**

```
from collections import Counter
c = Counter(aSeries)
l = c.items()
l.sort(key = lambda item: item[0])
print l
```

**Example of list printed**

```
[(u'1', 23), (u'2', 24), (u'3', 23), (u'4', 17), (u'5', 25), (u'6', 23), (u'7', 22)]
```

**Attempting to append**

```
self.treestore.append(path, [l])
```

Image of list appended: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3BGU.png

I would like the list to be appended like so

```
* 1: 23
* 2: 24
* 3: 23
* 4: 17
* 5: 25
```

How can i modify the way the list is counted or printed so that it will play nicely with the syntax that treestore.append requires ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might depend a bit on your model, but how about something like this (i.e. append every single element of the list seperately to the treestore, which I assume to have only one column based on your picture):

```
l = c.items()
…
for (char, count) in l:
    treestore.append(parent, ("%d: %s" % (count, char),))
```

Comment: Thank you so much. [List image](http://i.imgur.com/PNfxP.png) all i had to do was swap the vales for my need and it works perfectly self.treestore.append(path, ("%s: %d" % (char, count),))